# How to fix blank output when printing the size of an Array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

When running the simple code below I want to check the size of my array with a printf statement to output the value of size. I believe that I have coded this correctly but the output is completely blank.

I so far have only been able to get this to work when reading from a file. I've also tried initializing size=0 which I already knew would not work. Ran code on Codeblocks only.

```
 int main()
 {
      int x[50]= {1,3,43,5,7,49,3,6},i,size;

      for(i=0;i<50;i++)
      {
           scanf("%d",&x[i]);
           ++size;
      }
      printf("The size is %d", size);

 return 0;
 }
```

This code should simply output "The size is 8".

Comment: Initialize `size` to `0`. Note that you can use `i` instead.

Comment: your value for size is uninitialized. C does not initialize values to `0` ... so before the loop, `size=0`... Also your code will NOT output size=8 because your for loop will keep running while `i < 50` and you are adding size.  If you want to exit when at the end of input you need an `if` statement to check for that condition, and a `break` whenever that condition is met.

Comment: **I've also tried initializing size=0 which I already knew would not work** Why do you think it will not work?

Comment: I am getting an impression that you think `scanf()` has something to do with your initializer list.  It doesn't

Comment: If you're trying to get the size of the initialization list for the array, there's no way to do that.

Comment: The initialization list is treated as if it has `0` after all the defined elements, so you could loop through the array until you get to `0`. That won't work if any of the initializations are explicitly `0`, though.

Comment: You could also change `[50]` to `[]`, then use `sizeof x / sizeof *x` to get the number of array elements.

Comment: @AhmedMasud ahhhh makes sense! I believe this is what I was struggling to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you expect your output to appear as 8.

since you have already initialized value of the array to 50 you will get size of the array 50 .

Comment: Well I wanted to code it as if I didn't know how many elements were actually in the array.... .. kind of like when using fscanf to read an array with an unknown number of real numbers in the array. Wasn't too sure if it was a good way to this

Comment: i would recommend use fgets over scanf ,if you give small space here or there it will be nightmare to detect what has gone wrong.